# Why does echo $VARIABLE, within a /bin/bash -c "..." section of a dockerfile run instruction, return empty on docker build?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

**Question :**

Observing the output (see below) between `--- echo home` and the `--- env`, `$GOPATH` is clearly defined as is `$HOME`. In addtion, the output of `echo $HOME` is visible in the between `--- start` and `--- echo home`. But, the output of `echo $GOPATH` between `--- env` and `--- echo gopath` is empty. Why?

**Details :**

**Dockerfile RUN instruction that has issue**

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "echo '-------------------------------------------- start' ;\
                  echo $HOME ;\
                  echo '-------------------------------------------- echo home' ;\
                  source $HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm ;\
                  gvm use go1.5.1 ;\
                  env ;\
                  echo '-------------------------------------------- env ' ;\
                  echo $GOPATH ;\
                  echo '-------------------------------------------- echo gopath' ;\
                  "
```

**Outout of docker build step for the above instruction**

```
Step 5 : RUN /bin/bash -c "echo '-------------------------------------------- start' ;                  echo $HOME ;                  echo '-------------------------------------------- echo home' ;                  source $HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm ;                  gvm use go1.5.1 ;                  env ;                  echo '-------------------------------------------- env ' ;                  echo $GOPATH ;                  echo '-------------------------------------------- echo gopath' ;                  "
 ---> Running in c079d62aa7eb
-------------------------------------------- start
/home/amebel
-------------------------------------------- echo home
Now using version go1.5.1
HOSTNAME=e611e15f9c9d
GVM_ROOT=/home/amebel/.gvm
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/overlay/lib:
PATH=/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/bin:/home/amebel/.gvm/gos/go1.5.1/bin:/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/overlay/bin:/home/amebel/.gvm/bin:/home/amebel/.gvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
GVM_VERSION=1.0.22
PWD=/home/amebel
gvm_pkgset_name=global
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/amebel
GOROOT=/home/amebel/.gvm/gos/go1.5.1
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/overlay/lib:
gvm_go_name=go1.5.1
GVM_OVERLAY_PREFIX=/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/overlay
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/overlay/lib/pkgconfig:
GOPATH=/home/amebel/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global
GVM_PATH_BACKUP=/home/amebel/.gvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
-------------------------------------------- env 

-------------------------------------------- echo gopath
 ---> db5582b888ab
Removing intermediate container c079d62aa7eb
Successfully built db5582b888ab
---- Finished build of amebel/golang ----
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your string is in double quotes, the variables in it will be expanded by the original shell that's running the command, not the shell invoked by `bash -c`. `GOPATH` isn't defined in that original shell.

Put the argument to `bash -c` in single quotes instead of double quotes, and it will be passed literally to `bash`.

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo "-------------------------------------------- start" ;\
                  echo $HOME ;\
                  echo "-------------------------------------------- echo home" ;\
                  source $HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm ;\
                  gvm use go1.5.1 ;\
                  env ;\
                  echo "-------------------------------------------- env " ;\
                  echo $GOPATH ;\
                  echo "-------------------------------------------- echo gopath" ;\
                  '
```

Comment: Single quoted strings don't need (or want) trailing backslashes.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not very familiar with Docker, I thought that might be part of its syntax, not the shell's.

Comment: @Barmer Thanks for the response

Comment: @AmeBel Please use SO's auto-complete after @. It won't misspell my name.

Comment: Neither am I. I suppose that's possible.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for that.

Comment: @EtanReisner removing the backslashes gives `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` error

Comment: @AmeBel For the single quoted version? Does docker require those for multi-line `RUN` commands?

Comment: @EtanReisner it doesn't detail anything about that. I tried the commands on my host and there was no issue.  I guess it is a bug or somthing else I missed. In any case thanks, it is good to know the difference.

Comment: @EtanReisner Just confirmed '\' is a requirement for multi-line `RUN` instructions as described [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16239#issuecomment-139613618)